# How to implement client/server encryption with GWT

Tags: gwt

I have already setup a entry form with GWT. My problem is how to encrypt the inputted data at the client side.
Is there any possible way to send the inputted data encrypted, especially the password to the server?
Is there a way to setup the encryption algorithm in the web.xml file?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should use ssl for such operations. Then transmiting data from client to server is secure then.
Second thing is that you shouldn't send unencrypted password. First convert password with MD5 and then send it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/LoginSecurityFAQ and http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/web/security-for-gwt-applications.